# What is platform string for iPhone 6 & 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6

What is the platform string for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?

FYI: platform string is important because it helps identifying HW model for programming purpose.

Below is my guess:

- iPhone 6 (GSM): iPhone7,1
- iPhone 6 (Global): iPhone7,2
- iPhone 6 Plus (GSM): iPhone7,3
- iPhone 6 Plus (Global): iPhone7,4

Comment: This actually might be a helpful question: The hardware model can - in certain cases - be used to determine the computing power of the device I'm running on. That can be helpful to decide whether to use - for example - high-quality rendering or low quality rendering in a game so that it looks and performs best, based on the device.

Comment: At least one iPhone 6 has been identified as "iPhone7,2": http://9to5mac.com/2014/09/09/iphone-6-ran-through-geekbench-once-again-suggests-1-gb-ram-dual-core-a8/

Comment: @ThomasW Thanks for posting the article. It's very helpful. At least, we know they all have "iPhone7" prefix just as I predicted. However, we still don't know what variant it is.

Comment: Any updates for iPhone 7 and iPhone 7+?

Comment: iPhone9,1 = iPhone 7 CDMA;
iPhone9,3 = iPhone 7 GSM;
iPhone9,2 = iPhone 7+ CDMA;
iPhone9,4 = iPhone 7+ GSM

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update: My company now has a verizon iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, here's what I've found

- iPhone7,1 = iPhone 6 Plus
- iPhone7,2 = iPhone 6

Old answer below for posterity.

---

So I've done a little digging around in [the IPSW files for iOS 8](http://www.reddit.com/r/iOS8/comments/2goddx/direct_links_for_ios8/). There are 2 files for the 2 iPhone  6 models; iPhone7,1 and iPhone7,2. The iPhone7,2 IPSW file contains a file named kernelcache.release.n61 and N61 is known to be the internal name for iPhone 6. Similarly, the IPSW file for iPhone7,1 contains a kernelcache.release.n56 file, and N56 is iPhone 6 Plus. Also, the iPhone7,1 firmware contains @3x image assets, and the iPhone7,2 one contains @2x assets.

Therefore:

- iPhone7,1 = N56 = iPhone 6 Plus
- iPhone7,2 = N61 = iPhone 6

There don't appear to be any variants of the 2 devices.

Comment: What are the strings for GSM phones?

Comment: I just got my iPhone 6 Plus (T-Mobile / GSM) and the string is the same as your Verizon phone: `iPhone7,1`

Comment: I wonder why the iPhone7,1 is the 6 Plus, and not the other way around. Maybe the development of iPhone 6 Plus was started/completed before the smaller iPhone 6?

Comment: It is interesting. The internal codename (N56) and model (A1522) is lower too. The project that became the iPhone 6 Plus starting first makes sense, but we probably won't find out what the real inside story was for years.

Answer (score 9):

Platform strings for the new iPhone 6, 6s, 6 Plus, and 6s Plus:

- iPhone7,1: iPhone 6 Plus
- iPhone7,2: iPhone 6
- iPhone8,1: iPhone 6s
- iPhone8,2: iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone8,4: iPhone SE

Also, here is the snippet with all platform strings since the beginning of time:

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6s";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6s Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"])    return @"iPhone SE";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (1 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (2 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (3 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (4 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (5 Gen)";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
```

Comment: you are wrong, it should be iPhone8,1: iPhone 6s AND
iPhone8,2: iPhone 6s Plus

Comment: Confirmed that my iPhone 6S calls itself iPhone8,1 (inconsistent, though it is!)

Comment: @PeterJohnson Thanks for confirming this inconsistent ids scheme. I've updated my post.

Comment: What about iPhone SE??

Comment: Found it! iPhone8,4
@Cosmin please update your answer

Answer (score 7):

If you look inside the device profiles within `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes` (Using Xcode 6) you will see:

**iPhone 6 Plus:** `iPhone7,1`

**iPhone 6:** `iPhone7,2`

Comment: Great find. However, it does not tell the variants.
iPhone 5S has 2 variants, but the profile.plist only shows 1.

Comment: The full file path:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 6.simdevicetype/Contents/Resources/profile.plist

Look for modelIdentifier.

Comment: That is the path for just one device, there are others.

Comment: Yes I know. Just want to make clear to others. 
iPhone 6 Plus path:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/De‌​veloper/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 6 Plus.simdevicetype/Contents/Resources/profile.plist

Answer (score 6):

The URLs of these pages on Apple's website (for "RF Exposure") seem to confirm:

iPhone 6 Plus: 7,1

- https://www.apple.com/legal/rfexposure/iphone7,1/en/

iPhone 6: 7,2

- https://www.apple.com/legal/rfexposure/iphone7,2/en/

Answer (score 2):

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IPhone

iPhone 6 Plus: iPhone7,1

iPhone 6: iPhone7,2

Comment: I saw that too, but we don't know what their source is for this information.

Comment: Actually they say: 

References
The Keynotes themselves
Apple.com

But I'm not sure this is a verified info

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be kept up to date with the most current models.

[UIDeviceHardware](https://github.com/fahrulazmi/UIDeviceHardware)