# Detecting device after iPhone 6 has been released

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, iphone-6

Is there any way to detect, whether it is iPhone 5, iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+?

Earlier I did it based on resolution:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size == 568)
    NSLog(@"4 inch");
else
    NSLog(@"3.5 inch");
```

But now all the resolutions (4, 4.7, 5.5) give me the same 568 height. So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Why do you need to find out? (This may help us to suggest the best solution.)

Comment: Why do you need to know which model the app is running on?

Comment: @MattGibson, I wanna know it to scale the content to be the same physical size on all devices

Comment: Shouldn't you be using auto layout for that?

Comment: Once you know the model number Apple will use, using the question I've marked as duplicate, you should be able to detect it (specifically the `uname()` answer).

Comment: you want to know this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756087/detecting-iphone-6-6-screen-sizes-in-point-values    i thinks

Comment: Refer this link, Its give you good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website