# What is the target resolution for iPhone 6 Plus apps?

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus

When developing an app specifically for the iPhone 6 Plus, what resolution should the app be designed for?  Should it be 1242×2208 or 1080x1920?  Will an app designed for 1080x1920 fill the entire iPhone 6 Plus screen?  Are there guidelines from Apple on this issue?  I haven't found any.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting iPhone 6/6+ screen sizes in point values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756087/detecting-iphone-6-6-screen-sizes-in-point-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's guideline for all devices is to stop hard coding screen sizes and use Autolayout. If yo are targeting the iPhone 6/6+ you can assume iOS8 and Xcode 6 which makes Autolayout much easier.

It you really want to work to a specific screen resolution, you should use 1242×2208 which is downscaled to 1080x1920 in hardware.

Comment: Thanks.  If I want full fidelity on the iPhone 6 Plus, and do not intend for the app to be run on any other type of device, should I design for 1080x1920 to avoid the downscaling?

Comment: Depends on the app and technology you are using. For UIKit and standard apps use AutoLayout. For games and 2D/3D you might wan to design for the exact dimension. In general, I would be wary of focusing on a single specific screen size. Make you app flexible.

Comment: ...and you can't avoid the downsampling on the iPhone 6+ it happens to all apps. Apps 'think' they're running at 1242×2208 but the HW down samples. So you should design for 1242×2208. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified