# What are platform strings for iPad Air 2 & iPad mini 3?

Tags: ios, ipad

What are platform strings for iPad Air 2 & iPad mini 3?

FYI: platform string is important because it helps identifying HW model for programming purpose.

My guess is that they will have "iPad5," prefix.

Comment: Why did somebody mark this question down??? This is an excellent question. I was about to post it myself but found this here first. Trung, I just upvoted your question from -2 to -1.

Comment: Dunno, @Todd. Though it's generally unwise to do much with platform strings, anyway — better to query for the specific hardware capabilities your app needs (e.g. OpenGL limits, camera resolution) so that you're ready whenever future hardware meets or exceeds them.

Comment: I agree "query for the specific hardware capabilities your app needs". 1) However, there are capabilities not listed by apple such as computing power... 2) Also, it's great for debugging. I included device HW model in app log so that I know what devices tester ran on.

Comment: Yup! And unless I'm mistaken, it's the only way to tell the difference between a regular-sized iPad and an iPad mini — a difference which can be very important in certain applications. Also, I benchmark my code on multiple iPad devices and know the limitations for each device in terms of computing power. There's no other way to determine this without running an actual costly benchmark at startup, so it's very helpful to have a lookup table based on the actual device.

Comment: @rickster — If you agree that this is a worthy question, could you please upvote it for Trung so he isn't penalized by the negative total? Note that two of Trung's other very similar questions in the past (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854244/what-is-platform-string-for-iphone-5s-5c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754693/what-is-platform-string-for-iphone-6-6-plus) were both significantly upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is complete answer with code snippet:

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad mini 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad mini 3 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad mini 3 (China)";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";
```

Answer (score 3):

For **iPad air 2** platform string are `iPad5,3` and `iPad5,4`

For **iPad mini 3** they are `iPad4,7`, `iPad4,8` and `iPad4,9`

You can see a full list [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models)